# Including a document to JSP using Spring MVC

Tags: spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a need of "showing" a word document in a jsp file, and when a user clicks on the file, it should get downloaded.

It is basically a Spring MVC application, the controller creates a word document and then returns the next view to be displayed to the client. This view file (jsp file) should have the word document.

The controller essentially just returns the view name:

```
@Controller
String handleRequest() {
    // Logic for creating a word document.

    return "nextView";          
}
```

It is in this nextView.jsp the attachment should appear.

Now, how can we "attach" the generated word document into the jsp file?

Any thoughts in this?

Answer (score 0):

Using an iframe with in the page, you can invoke one more requestMapping URI which has header content-type set to excel / word doc and that document can be displayed on fly. And after the iframe add a download link as shown in the below link.

Ref here : http://www.codejava.net/frameworks/spring/spring-mvc-with-excel-view-example-apache-poi-and-jexcelapi